# Concerning the Procedural noise's function, how would you define a squared magnitude in plain word?

Tags: noise

By googling, I have found some definition of *squared magnitude* [about mathematical plane applied in the gaming field](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl24ps-IZIU), but I am dubting this is what we would mean in the noise generation's field.

thanks for any hint

Comment: Let $n(\pmb{p})$ give you the noise value at point $\pmb{p}$, then its squared "magnitude" is: $n^2(\pmb{p})$. If the noise produces not a scalar, but a vector quantiry, then the squared magnitude is given by the dot product: $\pmb{n}(\pmb{p}) \cdot \pmb{n}(\pmb{p})$.

Comment: @lightxbulb You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @user1118321 Feel free to. I still don't understand what this question was about.

Comment: @lightbulb I too am not quite sure what the OP is asking, but I often used squared magnitude (or square of distance) in, say, vector quantisation when mapping vectors to the code book since one is usually only interested in finding the closest code.

Comment: @lightxbulb thanks for your feedback, I am discovering computer graphic currently and wondering how a square magnitude would be defined in the context of a Perlin's noise more specifically, procedural noise more broadly if it is worthy to precise it

Comment: @Webwoman As described above. Squared magnitude is a mathematical notion, not something specific to noise - so you can just take your noise and square it. If your noise is made of vectors - then take the squared length of each vector.